# The Longest Sequence of Blocks

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, pseudo-polynomial

We have n block $B_i$ $(1 \le i \le n)$, each block has 6 faces and each face material, is one of the k types (k is an input parameter).
In addition, each block $B_i$ has the weight $W_i$.
the question is to find the longest sequence S of blocks, such that fo each $1 \le i < n$:

S[i].weight >= S[i+1].weigth and

S[i].topMaterial == S[i+1].bottomMaterial

We can rotate each block in 6 ways.

When all weights are distinct, it is sufficient to sort the blocks by their weights,
then use dp[n][k] to solve in $O(nk^2)$, but what can I do if weights are not distinct? can I solve it in $poly(n,k)$ time?

Comment: The same algorithm should work. Why do you think something needs to be change?

Comment: When the blocks have distinct weights, only one permutation of blocks must be checked, but in the same weights, I think all permutations must be considered.

Comment: Right! Thanks..